# Changing function with borders on specific sides to also be able to accommodate corner radius?

Tags: swift, swiftui, border

So I have the following struct and view extension to be able to add to any view, any ideas how to fix the corner of the view in the image below?

```
extension View {
    func border(width: CGFloat, edges: [Edge], color: Color) -> some View {
        overlay(EdgeBorder(width: width, edges: edges).foregroundColor(color))
    }
}

struct EdgeBorder: Shape {

    var width: CGFloat
    var edges: [Edge]

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        for edge in edges {
            var x: CGFloat {
                switch edge {
                case .top, .bottom, .leading: return rect.minX
                case .trailing: return rect.maxX - width
                }
            }

            var y: CGFloat {
                switch edge {
                case .top, .leading, .trailing: return rect.minY
                case .bottom: return rect.maxY - width
                }
            }

            var w: CGFloat {
                switch edge {
                case .top, .bottom: return rect.width
                case .leading, .trailing: return self.width
                }
            }

            var h: CGFloat {
                switch edge {
                case .top, .bottom: return self.width
                case .leading, .trailing: return rect.height
                }
            }
            path.addPath(Path(CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: w, height: h)))
        }
        return path
    }
}
```

I tried attaching it to a VStack as follows:

```
VStack {
    // content
}
.clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
.border(width: 1, edges: [.leading, .bottom, .trailing], color: Color.black)
```

The only problem is that it ends up looking like this:

[image: As you can see, the bottom right corner edge doesn't conform to the clipped shape]

Comment: Clipping does not change drawing path. You need to update you `EdgeBorder` to draw rounds explicitly by path. Now it is just square.

Comment: @Asperi Is there a way to not explicitly define the path in the function? As in, can I have the border accommodate the shape of whatever view it is being applied to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is from your `EdgeBorder` shape. It ONLY support borders without corners, it just adds one line for each edge to the final Path.
To resolve please try

1. Add one more param `cornerRadius` when init the shape
2. Rework the algorithm to create Path

   ```
   c - c
   |   |
   c - c
   ```

Enable a corner only when 2 side exist.

```
    var width: CGFloat
    var edges: [Edge]
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        //1. build new rect
        //2. build corners
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: newRect, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: cornerRadius, height: cornerRadius))
        return Path(path.cgPath)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I round the borders like this with the view

```
                layerMinY
             O ----------- O
  layerMinX  |             | layerMaxX
             |             |
             O ----------- O
               layerMaxY

    self.myView.layer.borderWidth = 2
    self.myView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.myView.clipsToBounds = true
    self.myView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    self.myView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner, 
                                      .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As the comment said, clipping doesn't change the drawing path of the initial rectangle. Changing the border width to 0 should remove the outline rectangle.

Comment: Right, but I don't just want to remove the border, I want to have it follow the curve of the view it's attached to, if that makes sense